# How to perform click event on an element present in the anchor tag?

Tags: watin

```
<div class="buttonClear_bottomRight">
    <div class="buttonBlueOnWhite">
        <a onclick="$find('{0}').close(true); callPostBackFromAlert();" href="#">Ok</a><div
            class='rightImg'>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

In the above code i wanted to click on Ok button present in the anchor tag.But an id is not generated because of which i cannot directly perform a click action. I tried a work around mentioned below.

```
IElementContainer elm_container = (IElementContainer)pw.Element(Find.ByClass(classname));
foreach (Element element in elm_container.Elements)
{
  if (element.TagName.ToString().ToUpper() == "A")
  {
    element.Click();
  }
}
```

But here `elm_container` returns null for intial instances due to which we cannot traverse through it. Is there any other easy method to do it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this...

```
Div div = browser.Div(Find.ByClass("buttonClear_bottomRight")).Div(Find.ByClass("buttonBlueOnWhite"));
Debug.Assert(div.Exists);
Link link = div.Link(lnk => lnk.GetAttributeValue("onclick").ToLower().Contains(".close(true)"));
Debug.Assert(link.Exists);
link.Click();
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

You can simply Click on the link by finding its text

```
var OkButton = Browser.Link(Find.ByText("Ok"));

    if(!OkButton.Exists)
    {
    \\Log error here
    }
    OkButton.Click();
    Browser.WaitForCompplete();
```

Or you can find the div containing the link like,

```
var ContainerDiv = Browser.Div(Find.ByClass("buttonBlueOnWhite"));
if(!ContainerDiv.Exists)
{
 \\Log error here
}

ContainerDiv.Links.First().Click();
Browser.WaitForComplete();
```